# How to use Windows Media Foundation instead DirectShow Editing Services?

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer, directshow, ms-media-foundation

I am developing a non-linear video editor. I need to have the support timeline, mixing of audio streams, the transitions between videos, etc. These all features are in DirectShow Editing Services, but it is no longer supported in the new versions of Windows. Instead, offer to use Microsoft Media Foundation. Is it possible to implement the same functionality in the MF or is using other SDK? For example, gstreamer. Maybe someone will recommend SDK for video editing on the basis of MF?

Comment: With Media Foundation you have to implement it all by yourself. For instance: video trimming could be implemented by Source Reader to Sink Writer and you have to manipulate the samples manually to compare their timestamps with the required range etc. I'm currently involved in a similar project and it works.

Comment: You can test the MFCopy Media Foundation example: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mfnode/. It supports video trimming. You can use it as a starting point for implementing DirectShow Editing Services features using Media Foundation.

Comment: MF proposes also use IMFTopology and custom session. Should I use this approach or a faster and more stable to use the Source Reader and Writer for the development of non-linear video processing?

Comment: With Source Reader/Sink Writer approach the app has more control over the timestamps as opposed to IMFMediaSession and IMFTopology approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Media Foundation you have to implement it all by yourself. For instance: video trimming could be implemented by Source Reader to Sink Writer and you have to manipulate the samples manually to compare their timestamps with the required range etc. Trimming has been implemented in the MFCopy Media Foundation example already. MFCopy uses the Source Reader/Sink Writer approach, because this way the app has more control over the timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

For a Windows 10 UWP App you can use the [Windows.Media.Editing.MediaComposition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn652646) class.